# Using DateTime expressions in ADF Dataflow

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory, dataflow

I am using a stored procedure in ADF Dataflow.
I want to be able to pass the parameter (AccountingPeriod) to retrieve only last 4 months of transactions.

The format of AccountingPeriod Parameter in SQL Stored Proc is:
MMM YY, multiple can join with “,” e.g. Jun 2019, Jun 2021

How can I write an expression in the ADF dataflow expression builder for this parameter to give last 4 months of data?
I used the below expression but I don't think it works in my case as I get an error when loading preview.

[image: Expression used]

[image: The error I get]

Answer (score 0):

In your Parameters for the data flow (on the pipeline itself), change AccountingPeriod to be a string and add in a pipeline expression of `@formatDateTime(subtractFromTime(utcNow(),4,'Month'),'MMM yyyy')` (this will evaluate to "Sep 2022" currently).

I'm unsure if you meant it needed to be 'MMM yyyy' (Sep 2022) format or 'MMM yy' (Sep 22), but you can exchange those if needed.

[image: AccountingPeriod]

Comment: I did what youve mentioned but I still get an error saying I havent entered and expression for my parameter in my Dataflow.

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate??

Comment: In the pipeline that calls the data flow, when you select the data flow, you have the options in the screenshot. When you select Parameters, you should see the AccountingPeriod parameter that you've created, and this will pass the value you provide it into the dataflow.

Here's the code for an example of what I'm talking about:

Pipeline: https://pastebin.com/smWQQS8g
Dataflow: https://pastebin.com/dz6CcRbv

Comment: Thanks. I only see the values for September dates now? But I want to see all the data for the last 4 months, not the last 4th month? Can I tweak the expression somehow ?

Comment: If the AccountingPeriod is like SEP 2021, that means it's being stored as a string, you should be able to cast the values as DATE and search for CAST(AccountingPeriod as DATE) >= CAST(@AccountingPeriod as DATE)

So you want to make this edit in your query of the data.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So basically I have to change the stored procedure query ?? Not the queries in ADF?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you need to do at this point.

If this solution provided the answers you needed in order to solve your problem, feel free to mark it as the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like that the proc only returns the data for only one month  , As suggested by @Azhkanizkael you will have to update the logic in proc .

I think you can also think about using the data flow inside a for loop and pass the month , year as a parameter . In this implementation your loop will run for 4 times, but the month will be different each time .

Comment: No, the proc when queried in SQL using comma delimiters returns values for all months provided. For example in SQLl if I call the parameter and say @AccountingPeriod = 'Sep 2021, Oct 2021, Nov 2021' I get values for all 3 months. However, I want this to be dynamic and in ADF. Thank you for your suggestion I'll try and give it a go.